# I cannot upgrade gradle wrapper version 6.7 to 7.0.2

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I tried to upgrade wrapper version 6.7 to 7.0.2 in our Spring boot application,
but I couldn't.
I need to upgrade wrapper version to can upgrade Spring boot version, because when I upgrade spring version to 2.5.2

I got this kind of error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':copyContracts' (type 'ContractsCopyTask').
  - Type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.backupContractsFolder' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' is writable.
    
    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' are already mutable.
    
    Possible solution: Remove the 'setBackupContractsFolder' method.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.

  - Type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsDirectoryPath' is missing an input or output annotation.
    
    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - Type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsMode' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' is writable.
    
    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' are already mutable.
    
    Possible solution: Remove the 'setContractsMode' method.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
  - Type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.contractsPath' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' is writable.
    
    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' are already mutable.
    
    Possible solution: Remove the 'setContractsPath' method.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
  - Type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask' property 'config.copiedContractsFolder' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' is writable.
    
    Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty' are already mutable.
    
    Possible solution: Remove the 'setCopiedContractsFolder' method.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
```

[this is my gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZYDy.png)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking (a question usually ends with a question mark). But when upgrading Gradle to a new major version, you have to ensure that the plugins you use are compatible with it. Often that means you have to upgrade the plugins too (in your case, the Spring Cloud Contract library).